# How to line up radio buttons with text

Tags: radio-button

I have this code but the radio buttons aren’t alined with text. How can I fix it?

```
<p class="cart-attribute__field">
  <label >Izberi katero obliko želiš:</label><br>
  <input required class="required" type="radio" name="attributes[Izberi katero obliko želiš]" value="1"{% if cart.attributes["Izberi katero obliko želiš"] == "1" %} checked{% endif %}> <span>1</span><br>
  <input required class="required" type="radio" name="attributes[Izberi katero obliko želiš]" value="2"{% if cart.attributes["Izberi katero obliko želiš"] == "2" %} checked{% endif %}> <span>2</span><br>
  <input required class="required" type="radio" name="attributes[Izberi katero obliko želiš]" value="3"{% if cart.attributes["Izberi katero obliko želiš"] == "3" %} checked{% endif %}> <span>3</span><br>
</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this from W3Schools : [radio buttons]
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio